Mutate a column in Ibis when column name has spaces
Given a dataframe that has a column with a space:
ibis.memtable({
    'colname with space': ['a', 'b', 'c']
})

I want to mutate this column. How do I reference it in the .mutate method? One way is table['colname with space'], however I consider this at best a workaround that doesn't work with anonymous tables.

In short, underscore with brakets.
import ibis
from ibis import _

ibis.memtable(
    {'colname with space': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
    )\
    .mutate(new_col = _['colname with space'].upper())

